# How can I set alternate color for both rows and columns using javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

**I am creating a table by user inputs.
User will input the height(number of rows) and width(number of columns) and it will create the table.
Post creation of table I want to format the row and column in my table.
I want to apply alternate colors for row and columns.**

**Here is my code:**

````
 function createGrid()
 {
 var num_rows = document.getElementById('row').value;
 var num_cols = document.getElementById('col').value;
 var theader = 
 '<table id="tblMain" border="1" >\n';
 var tbody = '';

 for( var i=0; i<num_rows;i++)
 {
     tbody += '<tr>';
     for( var j=0; j<num_cols;j++)
     {
         tbody += '<td>';
         tbody += 'Cell ' + i + ',' + j;
         tbody += '</td>';
     }
     tbody += '</tr>\n';
 }
 var tfooter = '</table>';
 document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

  }

   </script>
   <style>
   td{
    background: yellow;
  }

 tr td:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: red;
   }
 } 
 </style>

 <body>
 <form name="tablegen">
 <label>Width: <input type="text" name="col" id="col"/></label><br/>
 <label>Height: <input type="text" name="row" id="row"/></label><br />
 <input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createGrid();'/>
 </form>
 <div id="wrapper"></div>```


 **I want my table in the folowing format(Red and green are the colors for the rows and columns):**

 |Red    |   Green  |    Red     |   Green |
 |Green  |   Red    |   Green    |   Red   |
 |Red    |   Green  |    Red     |   Green |
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using `table` you can use something like this:

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

if you're looking for **columns** and **rows** then:

use css for `td` if you want different color code for `columns`

use css for `tr` if you want different color code for `rows`

```
<table id="id2" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("table#id2 td:even").css("background-color", "LightGray");
  $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
  $("table#id2 tr:odd td").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rB6Md/)

Comment: Actually I want to add alternate color to every row and column. If i use your code it will color whole row or whole column.

Comment: Yep, added that as well, check fiddle, change things however you want.

Comment: @user2495 was the answer helpful or at-least it helped you to move forward?

Comment: I am unable to do.

Comment: I didn't get it, the code works correctly and fiddle too!